# How can I save Website data to file using VBScript?

Tags: web-scraping, vbscript

In the following code, how can I save the text to a text file (text.txt for example) instead of the current `MsgBox`?

```
myURL = "http://URL.com"

Set oXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set ohtmlFile = CreateObject("htmlfile")

oXMLHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
oXMLHttp.send

If oXMLHttp.Status = 200 Then

ohtmlFile.Write oXMLHttp.responseText
ohtmlFile.Close

Set oTable = ohtmlFile.getElementsByTagName("table")
For Each oTab In oTable
    MsgBox oTab.Innertext
Next
End If

WScript.Quit
```

Please, help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FileSystemObject's [OpenTextFile method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method).

You can create the FileSystemObject at the top of your code with your other objects:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

And add these constants:

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
```

If you want to append everything into the same file, you can create and open the file outside of your loop:

```
sFileName = "c:\text.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForAppending, True)
For Each oTab In oTable
    objFile.WriteLine oTab.Innertext
Next
objFile.Close
```

Otherwise you can create multiple files within your loop:

```
Dim iTableCounter
iTableCounter = 0

For Each oTab In oTable

    iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1
    sFileName = "c:\table_" & iTableCounter & ".txt" ' create a dynamic file name using table name perhaps

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForWriting, True)
    objFile.Write oTab.Innertext
    objFile.Close

Next
```

Comment: It worked! Is there any way to save on different lines in the same file?

Whether it's possible, Can you send me the code with this change?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, just need to use `WriteLine` instead of `Write`. I have updated the answer. Please mark the question as answered using gray checkmark to the left of the answer when you get a chance!

Comment: It really solved my problem. I already mark the question as answered. I am very grateful for your help!